# rails 4, form_tag as bootstrap 3 input-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to style my search `form_tag`, but apparently can't get it right.

I'm trying to style this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :revije, nil, class:'form-control', placeholder:'Išči...'%>
        <span class="input group-btn"><%= submit_tag "glyphicon", class:'btn btn-default' %></span>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

into this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I need to maintain the `form_tags` to have database search forms though. Basically I want the input-group where the button is merged with the search bar, and the glyphicon. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
<%= form_tag '/search', method: :post do %>
<div class="input-group">
   <%= text_field_tag :revije, nil, class:'form-control', placeholder:'Išči...'%>
   <span class="input-group-btn">
     <%= button_tag( :class => "btn btn-default") do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>
     <% end %> 
   </span>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and for clarity, you might probably want to move the `<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>` to a helper.

and also make the form as `:post`

## EDIT - original code edited after OP's error

Comment: this returns a syntax error at the submit tag line because of the <span> tags, `syntax error, unexpected '<' ...buffer.append=( submit_tag "#{<span class='glyphicon glyphic..` . This error repeats about 15 times along with `unknown regexp options - pa unmatched close parenthesis: /span>}", class:'btn btn-default' ` . so I should move the glyphicon span to a helper in my application controller? How do I call it from the html afterward? I'm new to ruby and don't really know much about how helpers work

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič, I updated my answer with the new working code :)